# Flutter Firestore doc get returning null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a document from a Firestore collection using the following code:

firebase_service.dart:

```
class FirebaseService {
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Map<String, dynamic> getProfile(String uid) {
    firestoreInstance.collection("Artists").doc(uid).get().then((value) {
      return (value.data());
    });
  }
}
```

home_view.dart:

```
Map<String, dynamic> profile =
        firebaseService.getProfile(auth.currentUser.uid);
```

When stepping through the code the profile variable is null in `home_view.dart`, but `value.data()` in firebase_service.dart contains a map. Is there a reason why this value isn't being returned in `home_view.dart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs a few edits, as the `getProfile` function is `async`.

```
class FirebaseService {
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  // set the return type to Future<Map<String, dynamic>>
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getProfile(String uid) async { // insert async here
    /// insert a return and await here
    return await firestoreInstance.collection("Artists").doc(uid).get().then((value) =>
      return value.data(); // the brackets here aren't needed, so you can remove them
    });
  }
}
```

Then finally in `home_view.dart`

```
// insert await here:
Map<String, dynamic> profile = await
        firebaseService.getProfile(auth.currentUser.uid);
```

If you plan to use the `getProfile` function I suggest you to use a `FutureBuilder`.
In you `home_view.dart`'s `build` function write this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
future: firebaseService.getProfile(auth.currentUser.uid),
builder: (context, snapshot){
if (!snapshot.hasData){
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
}

final Map<String, dynamic> profile = snapshot.data.data();

return YourWidgets();
});
```

And now you don't need to write:

```
Map<String, dynamic> profile = await
        firebaseService.getProfile(auth.currentUser.uid);
```

Comment: I think this is not the best way to `await` a value from a `Future`: `return await firestoreInstance.collection("Artists").doc(uid).get().then((value) =>
      return value.data(); // the brackets here aren't needed, so you can remove them
    });`.

I think you should simply use: `return await firestoreInstance.collection("Artists").doc(uid).get();`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `async` operation and you have to `await` for its value.

For reference, you can take a look [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) at documentation of how propper authentication and CRUD operations made in Firebase with flutter.